# É possível criar um widget com javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, widget

O javascript já tem várias apis para push notification, vibração (apenas no celular) entre outros, já é possível criar widget na área de trabalho do usuário? Ou, se isso é um requisito do projeto, devo criar uma aplicação nativa? Se é possível fazer, como? Se não é possível, já existe algum esboço ou uma previsão de quando seria possível?

Comment: Olha, acho que sua pergunta é ampla demais e opinativa, mas como estou longe de ser especialista nisso, não vou votar, nem sinalizar e nem nada. No entanto, o motivo da pergunta não ter recebido muita atenção pode ter sido por isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, se quiser e puder, pode editar a pergunta pra tentar melhora-la

Comment: @anderson o cordova provavelmente usa a [API Vibrate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate) por baixo dos panos, não fiz essa pergunta em relação a nenhum projeto, apenas para conhecer. Se já tiver algo ou pelo menos um esboço, acredito que a apple não tenha nem pensando em fazer algo, pelo menos por enquanto. Windows phone já morreu, vou nem perder tempo. Como me referi a um pwa achei já implícito que era para mobile, mas pra ficar claro, **o foco é android**

Comment: Resumindo bastante: PWA atualmente é apenas um atalho para o browser abrir sem moldura, e rodar um worker para gerenciar quando as rotas vão abrir recursos locais e remotos. Não tem nenhuma funcionalidade que "saia" do browser e rode no OS.

Comment: O downvoter poderia dizer o motivo? Como posso melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: Caro Guilherme, sou eu, o seu xará novamente, para ser sincero a sua pergunta não fala nada de PWA, no PWA até aonde entendo a aplicação tem que funcionar independente de browsers, então é praticamente o que o Bacco disse, então das funcionalidade citadas como "vibrar" já sairia da intuição da metodologia, acho que sua pergunta não é sobre PWA, então é um dos casos que citei no Meta, talvez a tag [tag:android] se encaixe, mas [tag:pwa] não se encaixa a sua pergunta e nem é o seu problema. Seu problema é sobre criar um "app" atalho, e se vai precisar ser hibrido ou nativo...

Comment: ... então a pergunta é sobre funcionalidades especificas de um sistema operacional (ou mais), então caberia as tags sobre o sistema, mas não sobre pwa, só pra deixar claro (ps: não fui eu quem negativou não sei o motivo também, só posso supor que a pessoa talvez não tenha entendido a pergunta, mas não posso afirmar nada). Aguardo sua edição a pergunta e terá um upvote meu para contrabalancear

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a pergunta poderia ser traduzida para "é possível criar um widget com javascript?", seria melhor? Que tags poderiam ser adicionadas no lugar de pwa?

Comment: Acho que ficaria perfeito o titulo, inclusive em navegadores antigos, era "possivel" criar favoritos, hoje não mais, mas vale a pergunta, só uma coisa, acho que o que vc quer não é widget, mas sim um icone como "atalho", inclusive o iOS tem (tinha suporte) a algo assim, mas não era via JavaScript. Eu apenas colocaria as tags das plataformas que necessita de tal funcionalidade, como Android e iOS (talvez windowsphone)

Comment: Estava pensando em um botão ou algo assim que quando fosse clicado fizesse alguma coisa no "pwa" sem precisar abri-lo, seria um atalho para determinada funcionalidade

Comment: Ai já não é pwa, pwa é metodologia, não é tecnologia. PWA é como faz as coisas, não o suporte de algo que o sistema operacional funciona em si.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você tem uma aplicação web (HTML + CSS + JavaScript) para ser usada como um [Android App Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview).

Para isso, você vai precisar carregar a sua aplicação usando um `WebView`.

De acordo com o [guia oficial de App Widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#CreatingLayout):

> Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with
>   Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based
>   on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view
>   widget.
>
> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> - FrameLayout
> - LinearLayout
> - RelativeLayout
> - GridLayout
>
> And the following
>   widget classes:
>
> - AnalogClock
> - Button
> - Chronometer
> - ImageButton
> - ImageView
> - ProgressBar
> - TextView
> - ViewFlipper
> - ListView
> - GridView
> - StackView
> - AdapterViewFlipper
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Que resumindo em português significa: **WebView não pode ser usada em App Widgets**.

Bem, teoricamente não pode. Parece que algum colega do [MacGyver](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angus_MacGyver), chamado [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927617/android-loading-webview-output-into-app-widget#33981965) descobriu uma forma de fazer [WebView funcionar em App Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927617/android-loading-webview-output-into-app-widget).

Que envolve carregar um `WebView` por fora, renderizar o conteúdo como um bitmap, e usar uma `ImageView` para mostrar esta imagem.

Não recomendo usar esse método se a aplicação precisar fazer alguma interação avançada com o usuário. Teoricamente **não existe como interagir com botões, ou qualquer outro apetrecho do seu app web**. Porque ninguém te impede de recriar a [tag map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) no seu app, mas eu aviso, isso é masoquismo.

Comment: A ideia seria criar um widget apenas com HTML, CSS e JS (se possível), sem ter que criar algo com java ou Kotlin que o usuário teria que ir até a loja baixar e ficar atualizando. Mas se não for possível essa é uma solução interessante (se, como disse, não precisar interagir com o usuário)

Comment: Uma solução 100% PWA, seria usar WebAPK, mas isso não pode ser usado como App Widget.